# Dagger Hilt Missing/Binding interface with generics

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am using Dagger Hilt to provide the dependencies in the app. I have the following classes to implement use cases:

BaseUseCase.kt

```
interface BaseUseCase<in Parameter, out Result> {
    suspend operator fun invoke(params: Parameter): Result
}
```

UseCasesModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object UseCasesModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGetUseCase(
        repositoryImpl: RepositoryImpl
    ): GetUseCase {
        return GeUseCase(repositoryImpl as Repository>)
    }
}
```

GetUseCase.kt

```
typealias GetBaseUseCase = BaseUseCase<GetUseCase.Params, Flow<ResultWrapperEntity<List<ModelItem>>>>

class GetUseCase(
    private val repository: Repository
) : GetBaseUseCase {

    override suspend fun invoke(params: Params) =
        repository.get(params.id)

    data class Params(
        val id: Long
    )
}
```

The problem comes when I try to use the abscraction of GetBaseUseCase in the view model like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: GetUseBaseCase
) : ViewModel()
```

but it is working fine if I inject the GetUseCase implementation like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: GetUseCase
) : ViewModel()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AppClass_HiltComponents.java:131: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.....BaseUseCase<? super com.....GetUseCase.Params,? extends kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<? extends com.....ResultWrapperEntity<? extends java.util.List<com......ItemModel>>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

public abstract static class SingletonC implements AppClass_GeneratedInjector,

I have tried to return the abscraction of GetBaseUseCase in the hilt's module but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constructor inject your `GeUseCase` `implementation` and then `bind` the `interface` with it.

Reason being dagger doesn't know how to get instance of GetBaseUseCase

Something like

```
@Singleton // without any scope or with any other scope
class GetUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : GetBaseUseCase {

    override suspend fun invoke(params: Params) =
        repository.get(params.id)

    data class Params(
        val id: Long
    )
}
```

and then bind it with your interface

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
interface SomeModule {
  @Binds
  fun bind(usecase: GetUseCase): BaseUseCase<,> (your generic type)
}
```

It should work fine with generics as well - here's the thread of you run into any issue

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2161

If not able to do constructor injection - you can provide and then bind

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class YourModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bind(usecase: GetUseCase): BaseUseCase<,> (your generic type)

    companion object {

        @Provides
        fun providesUseCase(): GetUseCase {
            return GetUseCase(// required dependency)
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add `@JvmSuppressWildcards` - to avoid the error you are getting `@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type`

Here's the link for more info

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1143#issuecomment-381776533

Comment: I cannot use the "@Inject constructor" because they are in a module without dagger dependecies

Comment: Also I am getting the following error with @Binds method `@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type`

Comment: If not constructor injected - you can provide and then bind it with an interface.
Updated the answer.

Comment: Still have the error `@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type`

Comment: please add @JvmSuppressWildcards

Comment: where? to the bind method? same result

Comment: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1143#issuecomment-381776533

Comment: Ok, @bind error is gone but I am still having the first error

Comment: No, wait, you are right. Please update the answer and I will mark as resolved

Comment: Done, glad - you figured it out.